# php text formatting for a messy text

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to format a text but I do not know how to do.

I have text:

```
Row1
Row2
Title
text   _    text


text   _    text
Row1
Row2
Title
text   _    text


text   _    text
```

I want to modify it in

```
Title
text : text
text : text

Title
text : text
text : text
```

I want to delete Row1 and 2 but remain an empty row above.

To delete two rows empty in between text and text

And transform  `_   in :`

I try use str_replace and preg_replace but i don't know how to do.

ex

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $text = $_POST["text-ed"];
            $change = '  _   ';
            $change_r = ' : ';
            $remove_line = array("\n", "\r");

$rezult  = preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/', '', $text);
$rezult  = str_replace(array($remove_line, $change), array('', $change_r), $text);
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: you want to remove Row1,Row2 text too ?

Comment: i want to remove Row1, Row2 and empty row below text : text.

Comment: Are `Row1/Row2` literal texts or rows containing some text?

Comment: Contains a word at a row. Ex. Car/Barcelona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
<?php 

$text = "Row1
Row2
Title
text   _    text


text   _    text
Row1
Row2
Title
text   _    text


text   _    text";

var_dump($text);


// Delete rows
$text = str_replace(array("Row1","Row2"), "", $text); 
// Replace the underscore
$text = str_replace("_", ":", $text); 
// Replace all duplicate space
$text = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ',$text); 
// Replace all duplicate newlines
$text = preg_replace('/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "\n", $text); 

var_dump($text);
?>
```

Result:

```
string(103) "Row1
Row2
Title
text   _    text


text   _    text
Row1
Row2
Title
text   _    text


text   _    text"


string(60) "
Title
text : text
text : text
Title
text : text
text : text"
```

Comment: If use $text = str_replace(array("Row1","Row2"), "", $text); 
and
$text = str_replace("_", ":", $text); make change only for first str_replace

Comment: I need to change in this code because add text in textarea     <?php
       if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $text = $_POST["text-ed"];
            //change
            $rezult  = str_replace("-:-", "-", $text);
            $rezult  = str_replace("Barcelona", "", $text);
             }
    ?>

Comment: `$rezult = str_replace("Barcelona", "", $text);` is wrong -> `$rezult = str_replace("Barcelona", "", $rezult);` instead.